# How to get data from mysql table , if i have four kinds on records in a table

Tags: php, mysql

```
|id   | name | status | updated   |
|1    |John  |Active  |2018-04-12 |
|2    |Peter |Active  |2018-04-12 |
|3    |Kenny |Inactive|2018-04-13 |
|4    |Mike  |Active  |2018-04-14 |
|5    |Neeth |Pending |2018-04-14 |
|6    |Kenith|Inactive|2018-04-15 |
```

I need the array or records something like, as I mentioned below.

1st answer:

```
'Active' : [{
   id:1,
   name:John 
},{
   id:2,
   name:Peter 
},{
   id:4,
   name:Mike 
}],
'Inactive' : [{
   id:3,
   name:Kenny 
},{
   id:6,
   name:Neeth 
}],
'Pending' : [{
   id:5,
   name:Kenith 
}]
```

2nd Answer:

```
'2018-04-12':[{
   id:1,
   name:John 
},{
   id:2,
   name:Peter 
}],
'2018-04-13' : [{
   id:3,
   name:Kenny 
}],
'2018-04-14' : [{
   id:5,
   name:Mike 
},{
   id:5,
   name:Neeth 
},
'2018-04-15' : [{
   id:5,
   name:Kenith 
}]
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Show what you have tried. This is a simple select with ordering.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) 
if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and 
provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Read [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I need a single sql query for fetching 1st answer/2nd answer.
Using foreach and many loops and array_column i can find the same but i need a single query. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot produce the nested array data as shown in your question directly in a query. 
You can only get a flat array. You will have to create the array in PHP (or any other server language) 
by looping through the results of the query.

```
SELECT
    `status`,
    `id`,
    `name`
FROM table
ORDER BY `status`,`id`;
```

Pseudo code to create the array:

*Assumes query result is in an associated array **$allrows**. Output array **$rslt** will be structured as requested in the first part of output in the question.*

````
//  Assumes query result is in an associated array ```$allrows```

$rslt = array();
foreach($allrows as $rowno => $row) {
    if(!isset($rslt[$row['status']])) {
        $rslt[$row['status']] = array();
    }
    $rslt[$row['status']][] = array('id' => $row['id'],'name' => $row['name']);
}
````

For the 2nd answer:

```
SELECT
    `updated`,
    `id`,
    `name`
FROM table
ORDER BY `updated`,`id`;
```

PHP Pseudo code:

*Assumes query result is in an associated array **$allrows**. Output array **$rslt** will be structured as requested in the second part of output in the question.*

````
//  Assumes query result is in an associated array ```$allrows```

$rslt = array();
foreach($allrows as $rowno => $row) {
    if(!isset($rslt[$row['updated']])) {
        $rslt[$row['updated']] = array();
    }
    $rslt[$row['status']][] = array('id' => $row['id'],'name' => $row['name']);
}
````